# Solving a system in 3 variables problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need an answer for this problem, thanks in advance for the help.

Find $x$, $y$, and $z$ from the problem below.

\begin{eqnarray*}
-2x + 1 &=& 5 \\ \\
2x + 3y - 4z &=& 7 \\ \\
3x + 2y + 2z &=& 3
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Calculus (differentiation and integration), never mind multi-variable calculus, so I have removed those tags.

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they: Briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim. Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea). Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @john: Is there something missing on the $1$ term in the first equation? If not, that simplifies matters a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**

Since in the first equation you have $-2x=4$, then $x=-2.$  Plug in this $x$ value into the other two equations and you essentially have a system of $2$ equations and $2$ unknowns which simplifies the problem more.  Hopefully you can take it from here.